Make Langtu wireless mouse work with a different brand dongle
I have a Langtu brand wireless mouse, but I do not have the dongle for it. How do I get this mouse to work with a dongle from a different brand wireless mouse?

What brand dongle do you have? What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

There are a few manufacturers that have "unifying" receivers for their own devices, e.g., https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/unifying-receiver-usb.910-005235.html . You'll have to research the make and model of the mouse to see if one is available.

eBay may be your friend on this one...


How do I get this mouse to work with a dongle from a different brand wireless mouse?

Usually, you don't. Unless it's a Bluetooth mouse, in which case it should work with any modern Bluetooth dongle (or a laptop's built-in Bluetooth support).
But in most other cases, such mice use a protocol that's custom to the manufacturer – aside from Bluetooth, there is basically no standard as to what kind of data is transferred, how it is sent over radio, etc. (Sometimes it's not even consistent within the same manufacturer...)
Which means that about the only way to adapt such a mouse to a different manufacturer's receiver would be to replace some (or all) of its internal electronics with parts from a sacrificial mouse of the other manufacturer – in which case might as well just use that other mouse instead.
